# issues in web.config, what does this error mean?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to build a small fb application using asp.net mvc 2, and facebook C# .net 
From some reason, the code from the sample application doesn't seem to work for me.
Here's the exception I am receiving from my web.config file.

> Unrecognized attribute 'apiKey'. Note
>   that attribute names are
>   case-sensitive.

Source Error:

```
 <facebookSettings   
 apiKey="XXXX"  
 apiSecret="XXXX"   
 appId="XXXX" />
```

I've set this as part of the following configuration:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>
  </configSections>
  <facebookSettings
    apiKey="XXXX"
    apiSecret="XXXX"
    appId="XXXX"
     />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apiKey` does not exist in `FacebookConfigurationSection` from changeset 'b6900dde15d7' which is made by ntotten on 12/07/2010 08:11 AM.

Download / install last [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com) and take a look at [last samples](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation).

Here is [FacebookConfigurationSection source code](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20d07ae4a70e#Source%2fFacebook%2fFacebookConfigurationSection.cs). You will see that apiKey is not there any more.

Comment: well, now I am getting: Unrecognized attribute 'appSecret'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Where in the web.config do you have this configuration? According to the error it doesn't recognize the attribute `apiKey` which means can't read it. What else is there to say? I think the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: point is, that it's not! I've set the config like an example project and it's not working. I've set it directly under the configuration section

Comment: What example are you using? Do you have a site?

Comment: yep:http://weblogs.asp.net/kon/archive/2010/11/15/getting-started-with-facebook-c-sdk.aspx

Comment: For some reason the attribute `apiKey` is not recognized. Have you included all the references?

Comment: @Tomas Jansson, I really appreciate your followups. Yes, I have included all referenced libraries. Still, same error.

Comment: I recommend that you maybe ask the question on the blog, maybe the author can help you? I am sort of stuck and don't have time just now to download and try myself.